# How to plot matplotlib plots in sublime text 3 using Conda build

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, sublimetext3, miniconda

I've been looking this up for a while. Found a Stack Overflow question which deals with the same thing and the answer was to add "shell" : true
in the Python build file. I did that but because I'm using Conda and not Python, I put it in the Conda build file. But it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. In the Conda build file (**Preferences** - **Package Settings** - **Conda** - **Settings**) I added this :
**"run_through_shell": true**

Tip : When you open Conda-Settings, there will be two files in a split panel. Single click on the left one to highlight it and search for the keyword 'matplotlib'. You'll find this line. Simply paste it in the file on the right